# How to calculate the most stable component of the time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have several datasets with monthly Sales. I was asked to estimate the 'fundamental' level of Sales. In other words, the portion of Sales that is relatively stable and 'smooth' over the time.

My initial (and a very simple) proposal was to use **Moving Average** (e.g. 6 months). However, our new time series (orange line) will be often above/or below actual Sales (blue line). Next, I have decided to multiply Moving Average by the scalar (80% or 65%). This was just to lower the resuls.

Unfortunately, I think this is not the right way to go:

a) MovingAverageScalar80 (Grey line) is still above Sales sometimes. We can add min() function, but this may create sharp and jumping line.

b) MovingAverageScalar65 (Yellow line) is more or less my goal. However, here we can see that the line is sometimes far from the actual Sales (e.g. up to 1966)

Could you please suggest me any other techniqes I can use here?

File with data: [Dataset](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Am9f1Ox4hcd-_Hf1bFXaxVFB5btL)

[image: Sales and treatment]

Comment: Instead of *most stable* do you probably mean some sort of baseline under which the series never falls?

Comment: Yes, I understand it like this. I was also trying to google sth similar, but I am not sure about keywords...

Comment: Moving minimum instead of moving average might be a sensible choice, even if it produces a jumping line. Is a jumping line that much of a problem?

Comment: I think smooth line is a good starting point for the forecasting. Key observation is that there are a lot of spikes in the data that may create a misleading perception on the Sales (trend or direction). On the other hand, working with yellow line may be a good choice. We can prepare some analysis for the fundamental sales and next suggest any business strategy. Please see the very last observation - it is going up very fast. However, from the past we may expect that it will go down soon. Therfore, a yellow line may be a better choice to work with.

Comment: The way of constructing the yellow line seems pretty arbitrary, and that feels like a drawback to me.

Comment: Yes, agree. On the other hand, is there any other technique I can consider here?

Comment: Not that I can remember.